# how do we include connectionstrings in ARM template for function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

**How do we add connection strings in the ARM template to this section:**
[image]

Here's what I have tried, though it did not add anything to the Connection Strings section in the portal:

```
"appSettings": [
    {
      "name": "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions",
      "value": "disabled"
    },
    {
      "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
      "value": "default"
    }
  ],
  "connectionStrings": [
    {
      "name": "DefaultConnection",
      "connectionString": "[concat('Server=tcp:',reference(parameters('ccc_app_sqlserver_name')).fullyQualifiedDomainName,',1433;Initial Catalog=',parameters('ccc_app_db_name'),';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=',reference(parameters('ccc_app_sqlserver_name')).administratorLogin,';Password=',parameters('sqlserver_admin_password'),';MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Persist Security Info=true')]",
      "type": "SQLAzure"
    }
  ]
```

I'm using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2016-08-01/sites?tabs=json) definition.

**How do we add connection strings in the ARM template?**

Answer (score 3):

Setting the connection string as `Microsoft.Web/sites` is the solution I use:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
    ],
    "kind": "app",
    "properties": {
        "enabled": true,
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('webSiteName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "connectionStrings": [
                {
                    "name": "DefaultConnection",
                    "connectionString": "[concat('Server=tcp:',reference(parameters('ccc_app_sqlserver_name')).fullyQualifiedDomainName,',1433;Initial Catalog=',parameters('ccc_app_db_name'),';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=',reference(parameters('ccc_app_sqlserver_name')).administratorLogin,';Password=',parameters('sqlserver_admin_password'),';MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Persist Security Info=true')]",
                    "type": "SQLAzure"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is a working bicep example that sets the connection string:
https://gist.github.com/mjisaak/e7ddb416f86027658a3fa3d24feb3e0b

And here the corresponding ARM template:
https://gist.github.com/mjisaak/76fa5a534807f85bf2fa2b023d25fcc5

Comment: it doesnt work, that's exactly what i've tried

Comment: im going to update the api version to the example that you are showing and retest

Comment: still getting the same result, where nothing is actually added to the connection strings section in the app configuration in the portal

Comment: Hm, this is strange. I edited my answer with a full working example (just tested it), maybe you can figure out what is wrong in your template.

Comment: The main gotcha for me is that the connection string's value is named "connectionString", and not "value". Azure portal returns it as "value" when you click "Advanced edit".

{
   "name": "DefaultConnection",
   "connectionString": "<= not "value"",
   "type": "SQLAzure"
}

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use the subresource "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" for that.

In the example I added 2 connection strings - there can be as many as you want, and they can easily be passed as a parameter or variable as well.

```json
{
    "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": { /*your normal properties here */},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "connectionstrings", //This name is REQUIRED to target the connection strings section
            "type": "config",
            "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "YourConnectionStringNameHere": {
                    "value": "your connection string here",
                    "type": "SQLAzure" //Pick any of the types listed in Azure. 'Custom' if you are unsure
                },
                "AnotherConnectionStringNameHere": {
                    "value": "another value here",
                    "type": "Custom" 
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[variables('webSiteName')]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```